# Как правильно подключить стили css? Через link или через require? PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Как лучше будет подключить стили в PHP?
Через:

```
<style>
    require_once "<paht to css>"
</style>`
```

Или лучше подключить через `<link>` в теге `<head>` ?

Comment: чтобы подключить стили php не нужен... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />`

Comment: Вместо вопроса могли бы сделать через `require_once` и посмотреть что будет

Answer (score 2):

правильней через link, так как блок style служит для определения стилей непосредственно в html.

Answer (score 0):

в Wordpress, например, можно подключать и через require_once. Так как вся его логика и структура построена на php